# How to Change date format in php?

Tags: php

I have a date in an input
`15/01/1995`.But, I want to save this date in this format `1995-01-15`. 
I tried this code

`$date_format = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Data['date']));`

but, the output is `1970-01-01` which is wrong.

Comment: `strtotime('15/01/1995')` returns `false` because months only go up to 12. The reason is explained in the [notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
    $date="15/01/1995";
    $date=str_replace('/','-',$date);
    echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```